# pass NSMutableArray to UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

I have UIViewController that contains NSMutableArray , I want to pass this array to UITableViewController and view it on the table .. how can I do that ??

I mean I want to (pass) NSMutableArray or any Variable from UIViewController to UITableViewController not (create) a table

I want to pass newBooksArray to UITableViewController, I wrote in UIViewController:

```
mytable.gettedBooks = newBooksArray; // gettedBooks is NSMutableArray in UITableViewController

mytable.try = @"Emyyyyy"; // try is a NSString in UITableViewController
```

and in UITableViewController in DidloadView i wrote

```
NSLog(@"Try: %@", try); // out is null
NSLog(@"my getted array count: %d", [gettedBooks count]); // out is 0
```

any help ???

Comment: can you give me an example ??

Comment: what you are tried. show ur code.....

Comment: You need to start here: [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)

Comment: from here http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/uitableview/

Comment: ok I edited it to be try2 and tried, it still give me null

Comment: @Jenox `try` is a reserved keyword in `Objective-C++` not `Objective-C`, however, it is still not a good idea for anyone to use as a variable name or type identifier.

Answer (score 2):

[Creating a UITableView and filling with an array](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FoRO0dSNgRM)

I created the above tutorial specially for this problem.

There are also more methods you can learn about on the [developer documents](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource)

Firstly, you want to make sure you have the required delegate calls in your `@interface`:

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    NSMutableArray         * feed;
    UITableView            * tableView;
}
```

You want something similar to the following in your controller:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [feed count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [mutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

`numberOfRowsInSection` makes sure you actually load the required number of cell rows from your `NSMutableArray`. And `cellForRowAtIndexPath` actually loads the content from each row of your `NSMutableArray` into each row of the `UITableView`.

For passing it to another controller, don't you want something like this?

```
UITableViewController *viewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableXIB" bundle:nil];
[viewController setGettedBooks:newBooksArray];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I didn't watch the video, but you're missing a bunch of delegate methods in your example code here. They might help others who come to the question.

Comment: Any better? - I added the `numberOfRowsInSection` as well.

Comment: Yup. Sorry, I should have said one data source method. I wasn't thinking. Looks good now!

Comment: I'm using xcode 4.3 , I just want to pass array from UIViewController to UITableView Controller - not creating the table

Comment: mean I want to open the table and see the array got from UITableViewController and print it using NSLog

Comment: I've added some more to the end of the answer, see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

[UITableview tutorial and sample code](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/08/iphone-programming-tutorial-populating-uitableview-with-an-nsarray/)

Hope,this will help you..enjoy

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Tab Bar controller, and First View controller is table view controller and second is UIView controller. You can Pass data to Table View controller by followoing code segment. You need to declare variable called `arrayData` (NSMutableArray) in table view controller and set property (Since we need to access this from another class.) From this `arrayData`, you need to load data in tableView. In View controller class write following code.

```
    NSArray *viewControllers = [self.tabBarController viewControllers];
    MyTableViewController *mTable = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

    [mTable SetArrayData:arrayFromViewController];

    [mTable.tableView reloadData];
```

If you are using Navigation controller, you can do

```
    NSArray *viewControllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
    MyTableViewController *mTable = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

    [mTable SetArrayData:arrayFromViewController];

    [mTable.tableView reloadData];
```

Optionally you can use delegates.

Comment: sorry but I cant understand where the array content .. can U Illuminate more please ??